# Struggling With MVVM

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have a class named osmAppBarButton that inherits from AppBarButton (UWP) to which I have added a dependency property named ButtonState. (Enum Normal, Dim, Bright, Flash)

I have a Style used on all my osmAppBarButtons, that uses a DataTriggerBehavior to check the ButtonState and select the appropriate VisualState.

I was rather please with myself, as DPs and the VisualStateManager are all new to me.  Then I hit a problem..

How can I change an osmAppBarButton's ButtonState from the ViewModel without breaking MVVM ?  I thought about having a VM property for the ButtonState of each button in my view, but that would imply that the VM would have some knowledge of the View.

I think that the answer may lie with Attached Behaviours, but I haven't found an example that suits.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you get values from a viewmodel property to a dependency property is to use a `Binding`. Certainly not an attached behavior; I'm sure you *could* find some way to do that with an attached behavior, but just use a `Binding`.

`The viewmodel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and it must be the DataContext for the view where the appbar button lives, and you must not be shooting yourself in the foot by binding DataContext to something random in some parent of the appbar button.

Give the viewmodel a public property that raises PropertyChanged when its value changes. Bind to that property.

An enum like `ButtonState` with Normal, Dim, Bright, Flash values isn't the kind of thing a viewmodel should be aware of in a "proper" MVVM implementation. This isn't actually a silly point, either. I would suggest having the viewmodel expose its state through properties that express the viewmodel's state in its own terms (I could give you an example, if I knew what you were doing here). Maybe the viewmodel has a State that can be Normal, Busy, Error, Waiting -- those might map onto various ButtonState values. "Error" is a state of the viewmodel. "Flash" is *one of many* ways a view might choose to communicate a given viewmodel state to the user.

If the viewmodel expresses the relevant state using one or more properties with types other than `ButtonState`, you'd write a converter -- maybe a multiconverter -- to translate all that into a `ButtonState` value.

But it won't be the end of the world if your learning program uses `ButtonState` in a viewmodel, and that'll be simpler. So bind it to this:

```
private ButtonState _fooBarButtonState = ButtonState.ItsComplicated;
public ButtonState FooBarButtonState {
    get { return _fooBarButtonState; }
    set {
        if (value != _fooBarButtonState) {
            _fooBarButtonState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FooBarButtonState));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:osmAppBarButton 
    ButtonState="{Binding FooBarButtonState}" 
    />
```

But if you'd like to go with my suggestion to use a different state enum in the viewmodel, converters are quite trivial to write. Let me know if you hit a snag, but if you got a dependency property and viewstates working, you'll get it.